# IE9 altering content of <img> when printed

Tags: jsp, internet-explorer, jsf, printing

I am trying to print a webpage which is supposed to contain some images (icons). 
They are displayed alright in the page, and Firefox prints them fine, but  IE ruins most of them.

[image: This is what the printed icons look like in IE] ([Alt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfGux.png))

What is doing this, and how can I fix it?

These icons are being set in a loop in JSP:

```
<t:dataTable newspaperColumns="1"
    value="#{page.afterSales.leftOptionColumn}" var="row">
    <h:column>
        <h:graphicImage value="#{row.imgIsCompleted}" style="width: 16px !important;"/>
        <h:commandButton value="#{row.rowName}"></h:commandButton>
    </h:column>
</t:dataTable>
```

Comment: seperate images (16x16) or one image containing all statuses (16x80)?

Comment: Can you create [a demo online](http://jsfiddle.net) that we can troubleshoot?

Comment: 16 x 16 as you can see in the code part... the working icons are in a other section where they are defined static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that problem is unknown to me, i can say it is because of heavey CSS altought.. but as a work around i recommand you extract `target DOM element` with js, and create a new window where you have  the content free from CSS styles which can  genereate such a problem with `<img>` tags.

My work around:

```
function printCssCleanContent(){
                                var prtContent =  Ext.query('span[id*=overView]')[0]; // just the root dom node i choise to print (can be done with vanilla js or jquery or any other dom parser) 
                                var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=1200,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
                                WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
                                WinPrint.document.close();
                                WinPrint.focus();
                                WinPrint.print();
                                WinPrint.close();
                            }
```